# CSS positioning issue [img|span]

Tags: html, css, angular, css-position, positioning

I am pretty new to css and therefore not good at it. I need to position a text next to an icon. It needs just to go up a few pixels, as you can see. I tried it with margin, but it doesn't work. I'm just lacking of knowledge. The Snippet you see attached is located in a table-data field.

```
<td style="width:37%;" [class]="diffColorStatus(zeile)">
   <div class="status">
       <img class="statusIcon" src="../assets/rotZeichen.PNG" width="30px" *ngIf="diffColorStatus(zeile) == 'redMarkStatus'" />
       <img class="statusIcon" src="../assets/gelbZeichen.PNG" width="30px" *ngIf="diffColorStatus(zeile) == 'yellowMarkStatus'" />
       <img class="statusIcon" src="../assets/gruenZeichen.PNG" width="30px" *ngIf="diffColorStatus(zeile) == 'greenMarkStatus'" />
       <span id="statusText">{{zeile[0]}}</span>
   </div>
</td>
```

[icon/text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZ8SA.png)

Comment: You need to lear go to w3schools and you will learn it in 10m

Comment: u should provide more code, and do not put codes in image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very quick fix would be to apply the following style to the span (id = statusText):

```
#statusText {
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
}
```

What we are doing here that we are setting the span with relative positioning, so it won't wander off (like absolute) and set an amount of negative top position to align with the icon.